# Why am I getting the error 'TypeError: ResourceModel.__init__() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'width' 'height' 'n_agents' & 'n_resources''?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, agent, mesa

I am trying to make a multi-agent system using mesa, but the code won't run. I keep on getting the same error, but from what I can see I have added the correct parameters.

```
from mesa import Agent, Model
from mesa.space import MultiGrid
from mesa.time import RandomActivation
from mesa.visualization.modules import CanvasGrid
from mesa.visualization.ModularVisualization import ModularServer
from mesa import DataCollector

class Resource(Agent):
    def __init__(self, unique_id, model):
        super().__init__(unique_id, model)
        self.amount = 10
        
    def step(self):
        pass

class ResourceAgent(Agent):
    def __init__(self, unique_id, model):
        super().__init__(unique_id, model)
        self.resources = 0
        
    def step(self):
        # Find neighboring resources
        neighbors = self.model.grid.get_neighbors(self.pos, moore=True, include_center=False)
        resources = [agent for agent in neighbors if isinstance(agent, Resource)]
        
        # Collect resources
        for resource in resources:
            self.resources += resource.amount
            self.model.grid.remove_agent(resource)
        
        # Move randomly
        x, y = self.pos
        dx, dy = self.random.choice([-1, 0, 1]), self.random.choice([-1, 0, 1])
        self.model.grid.move_agent(self, (x+dx, y+dy))


class ResourceModel(Model):
    def __init__(self, width, height, n_agents, n_resources):
        self.grid = MultiGrid(width, height, torus=True)
        self.schedule = RandomActivation(self)

        # Create resources
        for i in range(n_resources):
            resource = Resource(i, self)
            x, y = self.random.randrange(width), self.random.randrange(height)
            self.grid.place_agent(resource, (x, y))
            self.schedule.add(resource)

        # Create agents
        for i in range(n_agents):
            agent = ResourceAgent(n_resources + i, self)
            x, y = self.random.randrange(width), self.random.randrange(height)
            self.grid.place_agent(agent, (x, y))
            self.schedule.add(agent)

        # Create a grid visualization
        self.grid_viz = CanvasGrid(lambda: self.grid.grid, width, height, 500, 500)

        # Run the model
        self.running = True
        self.datacollector = DataCollector(
            {"Resources": lambda m: self.count_resources()},
            agent_reporters={"Resources": lambda a: a.resources},
        )

    def count_resources(self):
        return len([agent for agent in self.schedule.agents if isinstance(agent, Resource)])

    def step(self):
        self.schedule.step()
        self.datacollector.collect(self)


# Create a ResourceModel object
model = ResourceModel(width=10, height=10, n_agents=5, n_resources=10)
server = ModularServer(ResourceModel, [model.grid_viz], "Resource Model")
server.launch()
```

I have tried rewriting model = ResourceModel(width=10, height=10, n_agents=5, n_resources=10) with model = ResourceModel(10, 10, 5, 10) but of course this makes no difference.

Comment: You need the `model_params` argument to `ModularServer()` to provide arguments to `ResourceModel()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `model_params` argument to `ModularServer()`, so it's not passing the required arguments when it calls `ResourceModel()`.

```
server = ModularServer(ResourceModel, [model.grid_viz], "Resource Model", model_params={'width': 10, 'heigh': 10, 'n_agents': 5, 'n_resources': 10})
```